# How do I write to a date-partitioned BigQuery table using a date based on the data itself in a batch Dataflow job?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a number of text files with data that I want to import to a date-partitioned BigQuery table from a `DataflowPipelineRunner` running in batch mode. Instead of inserting to the partition of the current day at runtime I want to insert into a partition based on a date mentioned in each row. (Unfortunately I can't use the `bq`command line tool to import the text files directly since I need to transform some of the values.)

I have tried to insert by outputting a timestamp from the ParDo function that is windowed into days and then applying that window and outputting table name suffixed by `$`and the corresponding date.

```
BigQueryIO.Write.to(new SerializableFunction<BoundedWindow, String>() {
  public String apply(BoundedWindow window) {
    String dayString = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")
                         .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Stockholm"))
                         .print(((IntervalWindow)window).start());
    return dataset  + "$" + dayString;
  }
})
.withSchema(schema.getSchema())
.withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
.withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

When I try to run this I am affected [by a Dataflow bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757718/why-does-my-dataflow-output-timeout-value-is-negative-on-insertion-to-bigquery). I also [found out](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/v1.7.0/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.java#L234) that

> Per-window tables are not yet supported in batch mode.

So how I can I write to a date-partitioned table with a specified date as partition?

Comment: This is now available both in batch and streaming modes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505534/writing-different-values-to-different-bigquery-tables-in-apache-beam/43505535

Answer (score 1):

If you have a relatively small, fixed number of tables you need to output to, you can create a separate BigQueryIO.Write transform for each table, and then [partition](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Partition.java) your data based on the date.  If the number of output tables is very large, there is not currently a good solution until batch Dataflow supports per-window tables.